# Ubuntu 15.10 2nd hdmi monitor blacks out

Tags: nvidia, sound, xorg, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I attach my Gigabyte P34Wv4-BW1T laptop to a 2nd monitor via HDMI. This
monitor blacks out randomly. I think it's random, at least. I'm not
sure if it's going into sleep mode or not. I went into my laptop and
monitor settings and turned off any power saving and sleep modes.  I
tried the nouveau driver, nvidia "proprietary,tested driver" and  the
nvidia "proprietary" driver and I still have the same problem. I checked my cables and they are not loose.

I'm not sure what type of log would help diagnose the problem. I did do a dmesg -T and couldn't find something in the log that corresponded to the time that this happens.

Maybe the "ACPI Warning" is a culprit? The same problem happened again and I didn't see the ACPI Warning in the dmesg log, though.

Another thing is that when I am playing music through the hdmi cable (the monitor has speakers) and the screen blacks out, the audio shuts off as well. So that's why I thought it was the cable, but the cable is on their tight.

I tried a disabling the nvidia card and using the intel card. That did not help. I also tried connecting via different hdmi ports. Still does not work.
Can anybody out there help?

Edit: i removed the nvidia drivers and disabled the nvidia card on my laptop. im just using the intel graphics. still having a problem. any ideas?

Edit: turned off power management (I think) and dpms:

> $ xset -q
>   DPMS
>   (Energy Star):   Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0   DPMS is Disabled

Edit: I don't see anything when I tail .xsession-errors

Edit: I installed Windows 10 and tried it all out. No problems with blacking out. It's not the cable or the hdmi port. Not a hardware problem!
I really need some help.

Edit:
It doesn't seem to be happening at a lower resolution of    2560x1080:

> HDMI1 connected 2560x1080+1920+0 800mm x 335mm
>        3440x1440      50.0 +   30.0
>        2560x1080      60.0*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my refresh rate. I have HDMI not HDMI 2.0
My refresh rate was 60Mhz which is too high.
3440x1440 60Hz is for HDMI 2.0, not what I have.

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 3440x1440 --rate 30
```

fixed my problem. I just made some scripts I have to run at login to run the command, which isn't too bad...