# Dual DVI Monitors not Extending, Lubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have recently returned to Linux and am attempting to setup my new PC rig. I've run into issues with the way my monitors are setup. I have done a fresh install of Lubuntu (You can view the version [here](http://pastebin.com/fpcEMt2Z)).I have connected two identical BenQ monitors to my GTX 980 both running DVI-DVI interfaces. Because they are both using DVI when I run `zrandr` the only interface I am able to see if DVI-O ([See the output here](http://pastebin.com/XGQ5BW8h) and correct me if I am wrong).

Using the GUI Monitor tool I am experiencing the same fault where it only detects one monitor as the output. I doubt this was a driver fault but I have tested `Using X.Org Z Server - Nouveau display driver` and `Nvidia Binary Driver version 352.63` and neither have allowed me to expand the screen (not that I expected it to). Just to confirm, the following may be of help: [LSMOD](http://pastebin.com/32UgfZD5) command.

Now I have attempted to run the ARandR tool to see if it is able to distinguish the difference, but AFAIK it's just a front end for running a script to amend the display settings, similar to the default tool.

Is there any method I can use to have both screens run using DVI interfaces and have them extend and not duplicate?

**Update 1**

Using my GTX 980, I run the top screen off HDMI to DVI and the second screen natively DVI to DVI, I receive the same fault as above.

**Update 2**

I am running one BenQ from HDMI to HDMI as the main display and the other display as DVI to DVI. Randr and the default application now notice it as a display yet the monitor itself indicates it has no video input - the HDMI cable cannot be faulty on this, as I nicked it from my other PC rig just now to test.

**Update 3**

I have been looking around in the community and have found the following:

[Second Monitor not powering on yet detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738028/second-monitor-detected-but-doesnt-go-on?rq=1)

[Second Monitor blacks out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720222/ubuntu-15-10-2nd-hdmi-monitor-blacks-out?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no real solution to this issue, I was required to use a DVI and Display Port adapter on the same graphic card to extend the two monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Check the BIOS settings and make sure any other graphics is turned off except for the 980. Also make sure you are using the Nvidia driver.
I am using two monitors on Ubuntu 14.04. There is a display setting that shows the monitor positions and if it shows the extended display you should be seeing that on your screens.
I turned off the sticky edges and turned off the Mirror displays in the screen display settings. Also set the launcher in the left display.